How do I get the exact buying price value of a token when swapping
is there anyway to get the exact token price when transaction happend?
i have tried to get the usd balance from code below, nothing works with .get_transaction method
txn_sig="9QW1nyhr4bNmS3kygLsB1GsyVMscz3u74P5fZuimst1fhu63tmdxdv1FHzb9VyaaPDXqCtKC4WA8rfQT9or9gaA"

txn_res = client.get_transaction(txn_sig, encoding="json", commitment=Confirmed, max_supported_transaction_version=0)
txn_json = json.loads(txn_res.value.transaction.meta.to_json())

I have seen something like this in photon-sol.tinyastro.io Whenever the user swap occurs to buy a token, at the same time it reads the transaction and gives the exact price of that token value in USD as seen on the below picture "PRICE USD".

is there anyway to do this?

You can create a function to fetch current token price using gecko terminal for example, one method to do that would be to listen for wallet account changes and whenever there is a wallet movement you can check whether new account (token) was added to the wallet therefore you know that he either bought it or received as airdrop for example, the same goes for selling or sending a token, you can tweek it your own way on how to check whether it was buy or airdrop if necessary..And if the script listen for new wallet change you can initiate tokenPriceCheck function in that moment so you will fetch current token price. you can listen on wallet changes using onAccountChange method that solana provides, you only need rpc.. it might not be the most precise as it depends whether ur using public rpc or private rpc , there might be few seconds delay on public ones but even on private rpc's.. but the easiest way would be if there was API that provides some price history of tokens, which im not aware of to be honest, didnt need to look for that
